# In Reactjs I want to overlap a image in a second image

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, npm, draggable

In Reactjs, I want to adjust an image in a second image, the first image cannot be placed outside the second image. It can only be adjusted or dragged with in the second image, also we want to calculate the x and y axis of second image with respect to the first image,

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

function ImageOverlap() {
  const [dragging, setDragging] = useState(false);
  const firstImageRef = useRef(null);
  const secondImageRef = useRef(null);
  const [position, setPosition] = useState({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
  });

  const handleMouseDown = (e) => {
    setDragging(true);
  };

  const handleMouseMove = (e) => {
    if (!dragging) {
      return;
    }

    const secondImageRect = secondImageRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    const firstImageRect = firstImageRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();

    const x = Math.max(
      firstImageRect.left - secondImageRect.left,
      Math.min(
        e.pageX - secondImageRect.left - firstImageRect.width / 2,
        firstImageRect.right - secondImageRect.left - firstImageRect.width / 2
      )
    );
    const y = Math.max(
      firstImageRect.top - secondImageRect.top,
      Math.min(
        e.pageY - secondImageRect.top - firstImageRect.height / 2,
        firstImageRect.bottom - secondImageRect.top - firstImageRect.height / 2
      )
    );

    setPosition({
      x,
      y,
    });
  };

  const handleMouseUp = (e) => {
    setDragging(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
      document.removeEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
    };
  }, [dragging]);

  const x = position.x + secondImageRef?.current?.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  const y = position.y + secondImageRef?.current?.getBoundingClientRect().top;

  return (
    <div className="image-container" style={{ position: 'relative' }}>
      <img
        src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dpqo4qwyi/image/upload/v1682704689/WhatsApp_Image_2023-03-20_at_8.03.34_PM_stuqbm.jpg"
        alt="Image 2"
        style={{ maxWidth: '100%' }}
        ref={secondImageRef}
      />
      <img
        alt="image1.png"
        src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dpqo4qwyi/image/upload/v1681501357/gildan-64200-01_pqyo4h.jpg"
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          top: position.y,
          left: position.x,
        }}
        onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
        ref={firstImageRef}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default ImageOverlap;
```

The code is not draggable and there seems to be an issue where if I use **react-**`draggable`, it doesn't show the correct position of the image.